# How to filter out entries in a data frame with specific and different values?

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, dataframe

I have this real estate data:

```
neighborhood  type_property  type_negotiation  price
Smallville       house           rent        2000
Oakville       apartment       for sale      100000
King Bay         house         for sale      250000
...
```

I have this groupby that identifies which values in the data set are a house for sale, and then returns the 10th and 90th percentile and quantity of these houses for each neighborhood in a new data frame called df_breakdown. The result looks like this:

```
neighborhood tenthpercentile  ninetiethpercentile  Quantity
King Bay         250000.0             250000.0         1
Smallville        99000.0             120000.0         8
Oakville          45000.0             160000.0         6
...
```

I now want to take this information back to my original real estate data set, and filter out all listings if it's a house for sale over the 90th percentile or below the 10th percentile in respect to the percentiles calculated for each neighborhood. For example, I would want a house in the Oakville neighborhood that has a price of 350000 filtered out.

I have used this argument before:

```
df1 = df[df.price < df.price.quantile(.90)]
```

But I don't know how to utilize it for differing values for each neighborhood, or even if it is useful to use. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant but you could join the percentile aggregations to each of the real estate data.

> df.join(df.groupby(‘neighborhood’).quantile([0.1,0.9]), on=‘neighborhood’)

On mobile, so forgive me if the syntax isn’t perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can set them to have same indexes, broadcast the percentiles, and just use `.between`

So first,

```
df2 = df2.set_index('neighborhood')
df = df.set_index('neighborhood')
```

Then, `broadcast` using `loc`

```
df.loc[:, 't'], df.loc[:, 'n'] = df2.tenthpercentile, df2.ninetiethpercentile
```

Finally,

```
df.price.between(df.t, df.n)
```

which yields

```
neighborhood
Smallville    False
Oakville       True
King Bay       True
King Bay      False
dtype: bool
```

So to filter, just slice

```
df[df.price.between(df.t, df.n)]
```